# How do I copy a static folder to both "dev" and "build" in Vite?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I'm trying to upgrade my Webpack based Vue.js project to Vite. I have folder structure like this:

```
 - src/
 - static/
 - tests/
```

In Webpack, I was using CopyWebPackPlugin like this:

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    to: '',
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
]),
```

And copied all files inside the static folder to make it available on both dev and build.

I'd like to do the same via Vite but can't figure out what how to implement it.

I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```js
viteStaticCopy({
  targets: [
    {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
      dest: '/'
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following changes should be an equivalent to your previous `CopyWebpackPlugin` settings:

1. `vite-plugin-static-copy` does not support an explicit `ignore` option, but you can set the `src` glob pattern to exclude dotfiles.
2. The `dest` should be `'./'` to copy the files into the root of the output directory (default is `dist`).

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: path.resolve(__dirname, './static') + '/[!.]*', // 1️⃣
          dest: './', // 2️⃣
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-copy-static-assets?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to answer the OP's question of how to handle copying files in dev. Even in the demo provided, the console reads that the files are collected by are not copied over until a build is ran.

Comment: This worked for me, although on Windows, I had to use `normalizePath`, e.g. `src: normalizePath(path.resolve(__dirname, "lib/scss") + "/*.scss"),` to make it work. This is mentioned in the docs of https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy